# Jmeter - Getting null value for variable on using regular expression extractor

Tags: jmeter

On my Response data I have:

```
<td>
<input name="ids" type="checkbox" value="1080" class="select-checkbox"/>
</td>
```

And I have others lines

```
<td>
    <input name="ids" type="checkbox" value="1081" class="select-checkbox"/>
    </td>

<td>
    <input name="ids" type="checkbox" value="1082" class="select-checkbox"/>
    </td>
```

On my Regular Expression Extractor I have:

```
Reference Name: test
Regular Expression: input name="ids" type="checkbox" value="(.+?)" class="select-checkbox"
Template: $2$
Match No.: 0
Default Value:
```

But always the result is Null. 
Please, What I need to change?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), consider switching to [CSS/JQuery extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead:

[image: CSS_JQuery Extractor Demo JMeter]

- With `Match No` == `1` you  will get `test=1080`
- With `Match No` == `2` you  will get `test=1081`
- With `Match No` == `3` you  will get `test=1082`
- With `Match No` == `-1` you will get:

  ```
  test_1=1080
  test_2=1081
  test_3=1082
  test_matchNr=3
  ```

---

If you are still looking for a Regular Expression Extractor solution - just use `$1$` as a template, `Match No` follows the same rules as for the CSS/JQuery extractor, see [JMeter - Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) guide for more details.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. The CSS/JQuery extractor worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex configuration as follows:

```
Reference Name: test
Regular Expression: value="(.+?)"
Template: $1$
Match No.: 1
Default Value:
```

Output / Extracted data: `1080` (if Match no: 1)

Output / Extracted data: `1081` (if Match no: 2)

Output / Extracted data: `1082` (if Match no: 3)

Comment: Thank you Adnan, but didn't work on my pc. The way that Dmitri explained, worked to me.